# New TV Episode Checker

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, node.js

My code checks if a new subbed episode of a TV show is out by checking the designated blog. The blogs url returns a json which is then parsed for episode number, direct video link, embed video link, and banner image. The retrieved episode number is then compared to the current episode number which is read in from a jason loaded on init. If there's a new episode, a notification is sent via Line with the links and banner and the current episode is set to the retrieved ep number and then saved to the json file. This whole process is repeated every 30 minutes (starting on Thursday) via cron until a new episode is found. There is also a small console I designed for means of troubleshooting and and setting variables during run.

I'm kinda a beginner with nodejs. How is my code performance-wise? How could I refactor this so it's a bit cleaner?

Much thanks!

```
var axios = require("axios");
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config()
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const RealDebridClient = require('node-real-debrid')
const RD = new RealDebridClient(process.env.DEBRID_TOKEN);
const LineToken = process.env.LINE_TOKEN;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var beau = require("json-beautify");
var readline = require('readline');
var events = require('events');
var consoler = new events.EventEmitter();
var state = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saveVar.json"));
var LastEp = state.LastEp;
var jobRunning = state.jobRunning;
var forcedRun = state.forcedRun;
var job = new CronJob('0/30 * * * *', () => getBlogPost(), null, false, "America/New_York");

var jobJobber = new CronJob('0/15 12 * * 4', 
() => { 
    if(!job.running){
      jobToggle();
      console.log("Blog checker Job started");
      getBlogPost();
    }

}, null, false, "America/New_York");

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var data = {};
var LineConfig = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/broadcast',
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + LineToken, 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: null
  };


var isArray = (obj) => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';



async function getCherryData () {
    let request, json, cherry;
    request = await axios.default.get("https://irozuku.org/fansub/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").catch( (error) => console.log(error));
    json = await request.data;
    cherry = {};
    
    json.reverse().forEach(json => {
        if( isArray(json.tags)){
            if(json.tags.includes(50)){
                cherry = json;
                cherry.epNo = cherry.slug.substring(cherry.slug.length-2, cherry.slug.length);
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(json.tags == 50){
            cherry = json;
            cherry.epNo = cherry.slug.substring(cherry.slug.length-2, cherry.slug.length);
            return;
        }
    });
    return cherry;
}

async function getBlogPost() {
    process.stdout.clearLine()
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
    console.log("\nChecking ep status...");

    let cherry = await getCherryData();
    
    let dom = new JSDOM(cherry.content.rendered);
    let banner = cherry.jetpack_featured_media_url
    let embedLink = dom.window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src
    let oldLink = dom.window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href

    let check = await CheckPost(oldLink, cherry.epNo);
    
    if (check.new) {
        console.log("New ep, creating link...");
        let newLink = await RD.unrestrict.link(oldLink);
        console.log("Link created!");
        UpdateLineData(parseInt(cherry.epNo),embedLink,(newLink.download + ".mp4"), banner);
        console.log("Sending notification...");
        makeRequest(LineConfig);
        
    } 
    else if (!check.new) return;
    else{
        logError(cherry);
        console.log("An error has occured, check the log file.");
    }
    if(job.running){
        jobToggle();
        console.log("Check post completed, Blog Checker Job stopped.");
        return;
    } else if (forcedRun){
        console.log("Check post completed forced run!");
        forcedRunToggle();
        return;
    } 
    else console.log("Check post completed, yet Blog Checker Job is not running...");
    
    if(!forcedRun) process.stdout.write("\nCommand: ");
}

async function CheckPost(link, curEp) {
    let check = {};
    check.errors = false;
    if (!link.includes("mediafire")) {
        check.errors = true;
        return check;
    }
    if(parseInt(curEp) > parseInt(LastEp)){
        check.new = true;
        LastEp = parseInt(curEp);
        UpdateState();
        return check;
    }
    else if( curEp == LastEp ){ 
        check.new = false;
        console.log("No new episode...");
        if(!forcedRun) process.stdout.write("\n\nCommand: ");
    }
    else check.errors = true;
    return check;
}

function logError(cherry) {
    let log = {
        link: cherry.link,
        body: cherry.content,
        CurrentEp: cherry.epNo,
        LastEp: LastEp,
    }
    fs.writeFileSync("error.log",beau(log, null, 2, 100));
}

function UpdateLineData(epNo, emLink, KodiLink, banner) {
    data = {"messages":[{"type":"flex","altText":`Episode ${epNo} is Now Available`,"contents":{"type":"bubble","size":"giga","hero":{"type":"image","url": banner,"size":"full","aspectRatio":"20:9","aspectMode":"cover","action":{"type":"uri","uri":emLink}},"body":{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","contents":[{"type":"text","text":"New Episode Available","weight":"bold","size":"xl","align":"center"},{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","margin":"lg","spacing":"sm","contents":[{"type":"text","text":`Episode ${epNo} is now up!`,"wrap":true,"align":"center"}]}]},"footer":{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","spacing":"sm","contents":[{"type":"separator","margin":"xs"},{"type":"button","style":"link","height":"sm","action":{"type":"uri","label":"Open Player","uri":emLink},"color":"#007bff"},{"type":"button","style":"link","height":"sm","action":{"type":"uri","label":"Open in Kodi (via custom Kore)","uri":KodiLink},"color":"#007bff"}],"flex":0,"offsetBottom":"5px"}}}]}
    LineConfig.data = JSON.stringify(data);
}


function getNextCheck(){
    if(job.running) return job.nextDate().fromNow();
    else return jobJobber.nextDate().format("[on] dddd, MMMM Do");
}

function setCurEp() {
    rl.question("Ep no: ", answer => {
        if (answer < 30 && answer > 0) {
            LastEp = answer;
            console.log(`   Current Episode Set to ${answer}.`);
        }
        else
            console.log(`    Input ${answer} is invalid or out of bounds.`);
        consoler.emit('getInput');
    });
}

var lastCheck = () => console.log(`    Last checked on ${job.lastDate()}.\n    Next check is ${getNextCheck()}\n    Latest Episode is Episode ${LastEp}.`);

function currRunJobs() {
    console.log("    Blog Checker Job is " + (job.running ? "running" : "not running"));
    console.log("    BC Initiator Job is " + (jobJobber.running ? "running" : "not running"));
}

async function forceCheck() {
    forcedRunToggle();
    await getBlogPost();
    console.log();
    consoler.emit('getInput');
}

function UpdateState() {
    state.LastEp = LastEp;
    state.jobRunning = job.running ? true : false;
    state.forcedRun = forcedRun;
    fs.writeFileSync("./saveVar.json", JSON.stringify(state));
}

function forcedRunToggle() {
    forcedRun ? forcedRun = false : forcedRun = true;
    UpdateState();
}

function jobToggle(){
    job.running ? job.stop() : job.start();
    UpdateState();
    console.log("    Blog Checker Job " + (job.running ? "Started." : "Stopped."));
}

function getInput() {

    rl.question('Command: ', answer => {
        (answer != 'getInput' && consoler.eventNames().includes(answer)) ? consoler.emit(answer) : console.log("    No command by that name.");
        if ('forceCheck' != answer) consoler.emit('getInput');
    });
}

jobJobber.start();

consoler.on('getInput', getInput);
consoler.on('lastCheck', lastCheck);
consoler.on('setCurEp', setCurEp);
consoler.on('jobToggle', jobToggle);
consoler.on('currRunJobs', currRunJobs);
consoler.on('forceCheck', forceCheck);
consoler.on('help', () => console.log(consoler.eventNames()));

getInput();


if(jobRunning) {
    job.start();
    getBlogPost()
}
else if(forcedRun) getBlogPost();

function makeRequest(config) {
    axios(config)
    .then( console.log("Notification sent!") )
    .catch( (error) => console.log(error) );
}
```

Comment: It's not a big deal, but you should avoid profanities in error messages. Some people could get offended by that when they run your code, and is best avoided.

Comment: AH sorry, I should've double checked before submitting;;

Comment: No worries, it happens. Thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of things you can clean up to make the code more clean and professional looking:

**Don't mix modern syntax with obsolete syntax** - there are some syntactical constructs that have no business being in source code nowadays due to their pitfalls and disadvantages compared to more modern constructs. The most prominent issue here is the `var`s - if you're going to write in ES2015+ (which you should!), there should be no reason to use `var` - use `const` instead. (You can also use `let`, but only when you need to reassign the variable, which should not be common.) ESLint rules (strongly recommended): [`no-var`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var), [`prefer-const`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const).

There are lots and lots of places in your code where these two rules will show you where you can make improvements.

**Destructure immediately** rather than creating intermediate identifiers whose sole purpose is to have values extracted from them. These lines:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const LineToken = process.env.LINE_TOKEN;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var LastEp = state.LastEp;
var jobRunning = state.jobRunning;
var forcedRun = state.forcedRun;
```

can be

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');
const { LINE_TOKEN } = process.env;
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { lastEp, jobRunning, forcedRun } = state;
```

**Don't forget semicolons** - unless you're an expert and can avoid the pitfalls of Automatic Semicolon Insertion, omitting semicolons (accidentally or otherwise) will occasionally cause very puzzling bugs. ESLint rule: [`semi`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) (strongly recommended)

**Avoid unnecessary anonymous wrappers** This:

```
new CronJob('0/30 * * * *', () => getBlogPost(),
```

can be

```
new CronJob('0/30 * * * *', getBlogPost,
```

**Use readable, understandable variable names** For example, someone who isn't familiar with the script might be confused with this:

```
if (check.new) {
    console.log("New ep, creating link...");
    let newLink = await RD.unrestrict.link(oldLink);
```

What's `RD`? It comes from `RealDebridClient`. Better to call the instance something like `realDebridClient`. Similarly, `beau` does not refer to a [beau](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beau), but to json-beautify, so perhaps call it `jsonBeautify`.

**To check if something is an array**, don't use `Object.prototype.toString.call` - instead, use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). Your custom `isArray` function can be removed entirely.

**Only catch errors where you can meaningfully handle them** - your current code has a bug here:

```
let request, json, cherry;
request = await axios.default.get("https://irozuku.org/fansub/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").catch( (error) => console.log(error));
json = await request.data;
cherry = {};
```

If there's an error, despite the `.catch`, the code will throw, because the `request` variable will contain `undefined`. Better to just return the rejected Promise to the caller and let *it* handle the problem.

**Declare variables as close to where they'll be used** as you can, within reason - this reduces the amount of things a reader of the code will have to keep in their head at once when reading a particular block. This also improves one's ability to declare variables with `const` (which should be preferred in nearly all circumstances). For example, the above code can be:

```
const request = await axios.default.get("https://irozuku.org/fansub/wp-json/wp/v2/posts");
const json = await request.data;
let cherry = {};
```

**Reduce repeated nested property accesses by saving the nested value in a variable**:

```
let embedLink = dom.window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src
let oldLink = dom.window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

This can be improved. Also, **only use methods that return a collection when you need to use the collection** - if you just want the *first element* that matches, rather than the whole collection, better to use `querySelector`. Like this:

```
const { document } = dom.window;
const embedLink = document.querySelector('iframe');
const oldLink = document.querySelector('a').href;
```

On a broader note: **Separate out functionality into different script files** to separate less-related logic and to make the code easier to navigate around. If a single file contains more than, say, 150 lines, that's *often* an indicator that refactoring into multiple modules is a good option. You could probably separate this out into at least 5 different modules.

Just for one example, this long function:

```
function UpdateLineData(epNo, emLink, KodiLink, banner) {
    data = {"messages":[{"type":"flex","altText":`Episode ${epNo} is Now Available`,"contents":{"type":"bubble","size":"giga","hero":{"type":"image","url": banner,"size":"full","aspectRatio":"20:9","aspectMode":"cover","action":{"type":"uri","uri":emLink}},"body":{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","contents":[{"type":"text","text":"New Episode Available","weight":"bold","size":"xl","align":"center"},{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","margin":"lg","spacing":"sm","contents":[{"type":"text","text":`Episode ${epNo} is now up!`,"wrap":true,"align":"center"}]}]},"footer":{"type":"box","layout":"vertical","spacing":"sm","contents":[{"type":"separator","margin":"xs"},{"type":"button","style":"link","height":"sm","action":{"type":"uri","label":"Open Player","uri":emLink},"color":"#007bff"},{"type":"button","style":"link","height":"sm","action":{"type":"uri","label":"Open in Kodi (via custom Kore)","uri":KodiLink},"color":"#007bff"}],"flex":0,"offsetBottom":"5px"}}}]}
    LineConfig.data = JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

is currently taking up a *lot* of horizontal space in the source code. You could put it into its own file *and* format it so that the general JSON structure is more readable, eg:

```
// getLineData.js
module.exports = (epNo, emLink, KodiLink, banner) => ({
  "messages": [{
    "type": "flex",
    "altText": `Episode ${epNo} is Now Available`,
  // ....
});
```

```
// main script
const getLineData = require('./getLineData.js');
// ...
LineConfig.data = getLineData(
  parseInt(cherry.epNo),
  embedLink,
  newLink.download + ".mp4",
  banner
);
```

There are lots of other miscellaneous improvements that can be made, but this should give you a bunch of things to consider for a start.

Comment: `The most prominent issue here is the vars - if you're going to write in ES2015+ (which you should!), there should be no reason to use var - use const instead. `

Hmmm, that might be a bit difficult. Since, for example, `forcedRun` is a variable that changes frequently and is used in multiple functions, notably `forcedRunToggle` as it switches it on and off whenever `forceCheck` is emmited. Setting it to a const would make it not be able to be reassigned and setting it to let would not let it be used inside a function which could be a problem for `getBlogPost`

Comment: Why would setting `forcedRun` to `let` make it be unusable inside functions?

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. For some reason I was under the assumption that if you declared a let statement outside of a function you wouldn't be able to use it without passing it.

Comment: Much thanks, My code's a lot cleaner now!